# Why use a comma after a print?

Tags: python

sorry for asking such a basic question but I always get caught up on things I don't understand and I know i'll just go crazy wondering why and will fear i'll forget to ask this question if I were to save it for later.

Anyway, i'm learning to program (in Python) by using Learn Python the Hard Way. I'm currently on Chapter 11 and it has a piece of code that it instructs you to copy:

```
print "How old are you?",
age = raw_input()
print "How tall are you?",
height = raw_input()
print "How much do you weigh?",
weight = raw_input()

print "So, you're %r old, %r tall, and %r heavy." % (
age, height, weight)
```

Up until now, i've just been parroting what the book says into my word processor but the function of this escapes me. Why are there commas after the print strings? Is it because it tells the interpreter to not end at printing the statement, but to wait for the raw_input()?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You can also pass a string to `raw_input` saving you a print, ie `raw_input('how old are you?')` and you'll have the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting a comma after a `print` call omits the new line.

```
>>> print 'a', 'b', 'c'
'abc'
>>> print 'a',
>>> print 'b',
>>> print 'c'
'abc'
>>> print 'a'
>>> print 'b'
>>> print 'c'
'a'
'b'
'c'
```

Of course, the interpreter would print immediately after you finish typing each line, but it's more clear this way.

In your case, if you didn't put a comma after the print, the `raw_input` would show up on the line after the question:

```
print "How old are you?"
raw_input()

How old are you?
12
```

vs

```
print "How old are you?",
raw_input()

How old are you? 12
```